# Transfer docusign draft envelope programmatically

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to create a envelope in draft status and then programmatically transfer it to a different user than the one I'm impersonating.

I can do this in the web portal but manually after the draft is created (see ui below) but I haven't been able to find a corresponding api method.

[image]

Also it doesn't seem like transfer rules can be used to transfer draft envelopes, but I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding that feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution we ended up using was to add an initial user as an 'editor' user. So the envelope is 'sent' immediately to the user responsible for checking the envelope for correctness.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make a POST call to

```
restapi/v2.1/accounts/<accountID>/envelopes/transfer
```

with this JSON:

```
{"carbonCopyOriginalOwner":false,"envelopeBulkTransferTypeId":"1","envelopeIds":["<envlopeId>"],"toUserId":"<userId>"}
```

---

**General tip:** if you can do something from the web app - you can [enable API logs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJYTDcc7cZw) and see what APIs are called when you do it.

Comment: Attempting to use this API yields a 400 status code: `{"errorCode": "API_RESTRICTED",  "message": "The API function is restricted and not available for general use."}`. I guess this is why it's undocumented.